# Grouping data by column name

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
[date1] [date1] [date2] [date2]

[Min:]  [Max:]  [Min:]  [Max:]

A         B       C       D
```

and my desired output would look like:

```
['Date'] ['Min'] ['Max']

[date 1]   A        B

[date 2]   C        D
```

How would I do this in pandas?

I'm simply importing a csv I have locally saved.

```
import pandas as pd

import csv

import datetime

SampleWeatherDate = pd.read_csv(weatherdata.csv)
```

[This is what my data looks like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZEnr.png)

Comment: Can you post your actual code to generate your data frame?

Comment: I get that but you should try to include a minimal example that can be copy/pasted into python to generate the data frame in your question.

Comment: I think you need add parameter `header=[0,1]` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), because header has two rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) if first and second rows are columns:

```
print df
  date1     date2    
    Min Max   Min Max
0     A   B     C   D

print df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'date1', u'date2'], [u'Max', u'Min']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]])

#transpose and reset_index
df = df.T.reset_index()
#set columns names
df.columns =['a','b','c']
print df
       a    b  c
0  date1  Min  A
1  date1  Max  B
2  date2  Min  C
3  date2  Max  D

#pivot
print df.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='c')
b     Max Min
a            
date1   B   A
date2   D   C
```

Solution with data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Date;2/4/17;2/4/17;2/5/17;2/5/17;2/6/17;2/6/17
City:;Min:;Max:;Min:;Max:;Min:;Max:
New York;28;34;29;35;30;36
Los Angeles;80;86;81;87;82;88"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=0, header=[0,1])
print df
Date        2/4/17      2/5/17      2/6/17     
City:         Min: Max:   Min: Max:   Min: Max:
New York        28   34     29   35     30   36
Los Angeles     80   86     81   87     82   88

#transpose and reset_index
df = df.T.reset_index()
#convert column Date to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#strip : from column City:
df['City:'] = df['City:'].str.strip(':')
#remove : from column name City:
df.rename(columns={'City:':'City'}, inplace=True)
print df
        Date City  New York  Los Angeles
0 2017-02-04  Min        28           80
1 2017-02-04  Max        34           86
2 2017-02-05  Min        29           81
3 2017-02-05  Max        35           87
4 2017-02-06  Min        30           82
5 2017-02-06  Max        36           88
```

```
print df.pivot(index='Date', columns='City')
           New York     Los Angeles    
City            Max Min         Max Min
Date                                   
2017-02-04       34  28          86  80
2017-02-05       35  29          87  81
2017-02-06       36  30          88  82
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the csv module, as you can read it directly with Pandas.

```
df = sample_weather_data = pd.read_csv(weatherdata.csv)
```

You're source data is formatted poorly, so there is quite a bit of munging to do.

```
>>> df
          Date 2/4/17 2/4/17.1 2/5/17 2/5/17.1 2/6/17 2/6/17.1
0        City:   Min:     Max:   Min:     Max:   Min:     Max:
1     New York     28       34     29       35     30       36
2  Los Angeles     80       86     81       87     82       88
```

First, note how the dates repeat with `.1` appended on the second date.  Also note that the first column is `Date`:

```
>>> df.columns
Index([u'Date', u'2/4/17', u'2/4/17.1', u'2/5/17', u'2/5/17.1', u'2/6/17', u'2/6/17.1'], dtype='object')
```

Let's extract every other date starting with the first (note that Python uses zero based indexing).

```
dates = df.columns[1::2]
>>> dates
Index([u'2/4/17', u'2/5/17', u'2/6/17'], dtype='object')
```

While we're at it, we can convert them to timestamps.

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)

>>> dates
DatetimeIndex(['2017-02-04', '2017-02-05', '2017-02-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

We can use the same technique to extract the City, Min and Max values. [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) is for integer location selection.  It uses (row, column) selection indices.  We are ignoring the first value (the zero index value), so we use [1:] to select all rows except the first one.

```
cities = df.iloc[1:, 0]  # Column 0
min_max_vals = df.iloc[1:, 1:]  # Every column starting at 1, ignoring first row.
```

We can index `min_max_vals` with `cities`:

```
min_max_vals.index = cities
```

We now need to create a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) with the dates and Min/Max and assign it to the dataframe.

```
min_max_vals.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, ['Min', 'Max']])
```

You're desired output above is missing the city, so I assume you really want something like this:

```
         ['City 1']        ['City 2]
['Date'] ['Min'] ['Max']   ['Min'] ['Max']

[date 1]   A        B       E       F

[date 2]   C        D       G       H
```

Transposing the results and unstacking:

```
>>> min_max_vals.T.unstack()
Date       New York     Los Angeles    
                Max Min         Max Min
2017-02-04       34  28          86  80
2017-02-05       35  29          87  81
2017-02-06       36  30          88  82
```

**Summary**

```
df = sample_weather_data = pd.read_csv('weatherdata.csv')
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1::2])
min_max_vals = df.iloc[1:, 1:]  
min_max_vals.index = df.iloc[1:, 0] 
min_max_vals.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, ['Min', 'Max']])
df = min_max_vals.T.unstack()
```